# View 3rd party api code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a third party url. Is there any way to view the third party api code. Or atleast is there a way to know to which parameters the api accepts.

Comment: No, you can't view the code. If that api doesn't have documentation or schema, you're pretty limited in your investigative abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third Party APIs are those developed outside of the user – that is, if First Party APIs are “in-house”, then Third Party APIs are “out-of-house”. These APIs are often designed for a blanket purpose — say, connecting to a server and delivering content to social media sites. As such, they are far less specialized than First Party APIs. This category also includes APIs that are contractually developed, that is, those APIs that you hire a developer or development team to create on your behalf.

https://nordicapis.com/first-or-third-party-apis/